# How do you install the old version of a Homebrew formula that doesn't exist in the current system?

Tags: homebrew, sphinx

I did my due diligence, and found that everything except the following was deprecated:

```
brew install sphinx@1.4.13
Error: No available formula with the name "sphinx@1.4.13" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

But none of the documentation explained what the current process is for moving forward at this point. Should I hunt for the specific commit, and follow that old process? Does it apply in the case when, potentially, the theoretical tap you would need isn't popular enough for that version to be maintained?

Edit: There are several things called "sphinx" and confusing one for another screwed me up. This question was meant to resolve an issue I ran into with a Rails project and the thinking-sphinx gem, which I was using version 1.4.13 of. I'd attempt to run the Rails server and it would complain about Sphinx not being installed. As it turns out, the project I was supposed to be working on doesn't even use thinking-sphinx, so I won't have time to even clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after the [Sphinx documentation tool](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/), it's a Python library, so I'm guessing it should be installed with pip? Or it looks like it exists in Homebrew as `sphinx-doc`.

But if you're after the [Sphinx full-text search tool](http://sphinxsearch.com), which is what the brew package `sphinx` refers to, there is no version 1.4.13 - it went from 0.9.9 to 1.10-beta to 2.0.1.

Comment: The Rails project this question was ultimately referencing does use v1.4.13 of the thinking-sphinx gem, but it wasn't the project I was supposed to be working on, so I'll acknowledge that the question I was trying to ask is probably not actually valid. Thanks anyway!